# Returning element of pointer array member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to pointers and having a hard time. I'm doin a predator-prey simulator and have a City class that has an array of Being objects, which are eventually to be cast as either Humans or Zombies. City class has an array:

```
class City
{
protected:
    Being *grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];//holds beings
```

I initialize the elements to null to start with just to keep it simple.

```
City::City()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GRID_WIDTH; ++j) {
            this->grid[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a method that should return a single Being from the array. **THIS is where I am getting errors**: "identifier 'grid' is undefined" or if I use the "this" keyword it says that's only allowed in a nonstatic member function.

```
Being City::*getBeing(int x, int y)
{
    return grid[x][y];
}
```

so I can access it from the main method and just print a placeholder grid:

```
City myCity;

int main(){
        if (myCity.getBeing(i,j) == null)
        {
            cout << "O";
        }
}
```

How can I fix this? Is there a rule of thumb for understanding pointers better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of the `getBeing` function should be:

```
Being *City::getBeing(int x, int y) { ... }
```

Comment: It was that easy. Also for future reference, I also changed the NULL initializer to 0 as I had an error in the main class of "identifier null is undefined". Thanks!

Comment: it should be `NULL`, not `null`. If you are using C++11 I strongly suggest you use `nullptr` instead!